# Minimising the application is affecting ManualResetEvent.WaitOne()?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

A bit of a strange one this. My application plots data on a chart, synchronised to a "signal" received from an external hardware device every second. Whenever a signal is received, a new point is plotted on the chart.

Much simplified pseudo-code:

```
while (true)
{
    _mre.WaitOne(1000);

   PlotPointOnChart();
}

private void SignalReceived(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _mre.Set();
    _mre.Reset();
}
```

A background task is responsible for polling the device (approx every 100ms), and raises an event whenever the "signal" is received.

The application normally works fine, but if I minimise the window for just a second or two then restore it, instead of seeing one or two new points on the chart, there might be a dozen or more new points. The only thing I can think of is that the `ManualResetEvent` is somehow being affected by minimising the application?

Not sure if it's relevant, but the "while" loop runs on a background task, started from a button click using

```
await Task.Run(() => ...);
```

Comment: So you see dozen of points but where did they come from? I mean if device really produces 1 point even second.

Comment: @Evk it plots a value that it reads from this device, which should change after each "signal". When I restore then minimise, these dozen new points all have the same value, and almost feels like the MRE is somehow getting stuck in a "set" state while the window is minimised, allowing the loop to repeatedly plot the same value rather than wait for the signal to indicate that a new value is ready. I really can't see how minimising the window would affect something like this though, so it could be that my problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Maybe you can provide more code, really hard to make any conclusions based on current code. I also don't think minimizing can affect event, which means SignalReceived might get called repeatedly for some reason, but you did not provide any code related to how it is called.